# The Seiberg-Witten equations for forms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

I define equations like the Seiberg-Witten equations for forms of a riemannian four-manifold $(M,g)$. $\alpha \in \Lambda^2 (TM)$ and $\theta \in \Lambda^1(TM)$.
$$
d\alpha+\theta \wedge \alpha=0
$$
$$
d\theta_+=\frac{\alpha_+}{||\alpha ||}
$$
The gauge group acts:
$$
f.(\alpha,\theta)=(f\alpha,\theta- df/f)
$$
Can we define invariants?

Comment: You're asking a big question (almost homework-like), like "show me how to build a cohomology theory", without demonstrating any attempt yourself, which is why I voted to close. I recommend understanding how the ordinary Seiberg-Witten invariants are defined, and check it for yourself (do you have an elliptic equation, transversality, appropriate index, compactness, etc.).

Comment: But there is a real analogy between these equations and those of Seiberg-Witten. The question deserves to be posed.

Comment: trivial remark: if we think of $\theta$ as associated to a connection, then the first equation just says that $\alpha$ is a parallel $2$-form with respect to that connection. The second equation seems to say something about the curvature of this connection.